# How to access dropdown selected item properties using angular 7 reactive form

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

In the following example I have a simple dropdown list which contains list of customers. When you select a customer from the dropdown list, I need followings to be done.

1. Selected customer name should be shown in the **`"txtCustomerName"`** text box.
2. Selected customer name should be shown in the **`"spnCustomerId"`** span element (I have done it in a way and I want to make sure if I'm doing it in a right way with the **Reactive Forms**).

In addition to above, I'm getting `"ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function"` error when the page is loaded. I found following similar post on stackoverflow but I couldn't find solid answer for the issue I'm facing.

[ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763296/error-typeerror-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function)

[ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function --> formControlName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804254/error-typeerror-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function-formcontrolname)

My component class looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public allCustomers: Customer[] = new Array();

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      selectedCustomer: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [],
        name:['']
      })
    })

    this.allCustomers.push(new Customer(0, "John"));
    this.allCustomers.push(new Customer(1, "Kumar"));
    this.allCustomers.push(new Customer(2, "Warma"));
    this.allCustomers.push(new Customer(3, "Sabitha"));
  }

  changeCustomer(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value));
  }
}

export class Customer {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;

  constructor(cusId: number, cusName: string) {
    this.id = cusId;
    this.name = cusName;
  }
}
```

My html page looks like this

```
<form name="frmMain" [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div>
    <div>
      All customers:
      <select (change)="changeCustomer($event)" formControlName="selectedCustomer">
        <option value="" disabled>Please select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let cus of allCustomers" [ngValue]="cus">{{cus.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
      Selected customer id :
      <span id="spnCustomerId">{{myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value.id}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      Selected customer name :
      <!-- I need to show selected customer name in below text box -->
      <input id="txtCustomerName" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please see above example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2a4mj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Please, take a look to my answer, the problem is not the related by others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the answers are incorrect. See the [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iy1bcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You are saying to Angular that selectedCustomer is a FormGroup

```
selectedCustomer: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [],
        name:['']
      })
```

But you're trying to give as value to a FormGroup an object when you use select

```
<select (change)="changeCustomer($event)" formControlName="selectedCustomer">
        <option value="" disabled>Please select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let cus of allCustomers" 
             [ngValue]="cus">{{cus.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is beacuse you has the error.

On solution is that selectedCustomer be an object, not a FormGroup, yes, a FormControl can store an object, not only a string or a number

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      selectedCustomer: []
    })
```

Of course, be carefully when you show the "name" and "id" using safe operator becaouse can be null

```
<span id="spnCustomerId">{{myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value?.id}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

TS:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  selectedCustomer: [],
  selectedCustomerName : []
})


changeCustomer(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value));
    let name = (this.myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value).name

    this.myForm.patchValue({
      selectedCustomerName : name
    });
  }
```

Template:

```
<div>
  Selected customer id :
  <span id="spnCustomerId">{{myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value?.id}}</span>
</div>
<input id="txtCustomerName" type="text" formControlName="selectedCustomerName"/>
```

Comment: You needn't add a new propertie to your formGroup, and not, it's not the problem

Comment: @Adrita Sharma, thank you for your answer. But your solution still gives me the mentioned error ("control.registerOnChange is not a function"). Also, without adding separate form control called **"selectedCustomerName : ['']"**, isn't there a way to get the customer name using "selectedCustomer" formControl?

Comment: @Prabodha I have edited the answer, you won't be getting this error anymore. Also don't forget to add **?** in `{{myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value?.id}}`

Answer (score 1):

The error happens, because you are initializing the form with the FormBuilder, but not all controls are present in the template (see here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463614/8712609)).

Try this:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  selectedCustomer: [''],
  name: ['']
})
```

Instead of adding a change listener, you can subcribe directly to the formControl as follows:

```
this.myForm.get('selectedCustomer').valueChanges
  .subscribe(e => {
    this.myForm.get('name').setValue(e.name);
    })
```

In the templatet:

```
<input id="txtCustomerName" type="text" formControlName="name"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, @riondo, I can not accept your answer as ok, the answer is other

Comment: @riorudo, first of all thank you for your solution and really appreciate your help. Without adding separate form control called **"name: ['']"**, isn't there a way to get the customer name using  "selectedCustomer" formControl?

Comment: You could do it like in the example from Eliseo and bind the value over the ngModel: <input id="txtCustomerName" type="text"         [ngModel]="myForm.get('selectedCustomer').value?.name"           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>

Then you can remove "name" as formControl from myForm.